# Is it possible/safe to resize non-adjacent GPT partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, gpt

I have a partition table that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QoAU.png).

I'd like to enlarge the /dev/sda4 partition (where I have Windows) by reducing the /dev/sda9 partition (where I have the /home directory with Linux).

But they are not adjacent, so I'm not sure if this is going to be trivial or if it is even possible. Thus, the question is: is it possible to reduce the sda9 partition to give few additional gigabytes to the sda4 one without destroying data in either partition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, However, make a backup of all the data you will need in case things go south.

Also when moving full partitions around, the process is bound to take many hours. And to do what you want to do you will need to use a live CD so you can work with and move your Partitions.

So yes you can, but I would recommend doing it only if you have to... Because if your system shut-down during this hours long process, it won't be pretty...

**THE PROCESS:**

Ok, before we begin...

**DISCLAIMER: *I (the poster of this answer) am not responsible for ANY data loss resulting from the use of this guide/answer. You (the reader) take full responsibility of your data and the potential lost thereof.***

Now that the Legalities are out of the way...

First and foremost, you need to boot into a Live CD, or an OS not on or using the partitions you want to resize. (Linux with GParted recommended) Make sure all the partitions you want to work with are unmounted.

Now you right-click the /dev/sda9 partition, (the one you want to take space from) and click resize/move. Resize it to where you now how the space you want for the /dev/sda4 partition. Make sure that the free space is to the **LEFT** (preceding) of the /dev/sda9 partition.

Now right click use Resize/Move /dev/sda8 and move it as far right as possible, hopefully to the point where there is 0 MiB (if you can't get under one or two MiB that is fine) following the partition. Repeat this step for /dev/sda7.

Now all you have to do is right-click /dev/sda4 and click the resize/move option and resize it with the arrows in the box that comes up.

Now all the options are pending and you just have to click the green check-mark to start it. This process will likely take many hours.

Again, be sure to backup any data you need in case things go sour.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The user is seeking on how to do this precisely. Just saying it is possible does not really help them accomplish it.  Yes;  I realize the author does not literally ask HOW to do it, but simply saying its possible, does not answer the author's implied question.

Comment: @Ramhound I revised it to include the process. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and useful, yet funny answer (I had to smile at the disclaimer). OK, then I guess the strict answer would be "no, it's not possible, but you can mimic that behaviour by moving the boundaries and data of all partitions in between". Is this correct?

I think I'll go for option B, which is to create an additional Windows partition to the right of sda9. It's going to be safer and easier. Maybe a bit dirty, but...

Comment: @Onturenio It is possible. All I mentioned was resizing partitions. I never added a new one. You can resize your Windows partition. I am just saying regardless, it will take some time because all the other partitions need to be moved over to make space. But if you wanted to add a new partition, you certainly can.

Comment: Ups, I just found out that indeed it's not possible to reaize xfs partitions. I'll have find a workaround

Comment: XFS can be grown, but not shrunk, the last I checked. Of course, you can do it by doing a file-level backup to your external backup disk, deleting `/dev/sda9`, moving your other partitions appropriately, creating a new `/home` partition, and restoring your data. You *do* have a big enough external backup disk, right? *RIGHT?* If not, ***buy one today!***